# Testing if the program is running correctly

Tags: c

I've got a program that it basically saying if the users input are inside, outside or on the rectangle edge and now i have written a test for this program that is suppost to tell the user if the test/tests are successful or not and i want to do do a test for every dot in a x-y table and then in the end tell if all test where successful or not.

The problem I have is that i'm not sure how to put it inside the base code so the test will work. Is it suppost to be in the beginning or the end(since the program exits after it tells the user where the dot is located)? Should I do an array for the test or not? Thankful for any help how to write the code inside the base code:

Comment: The code you linked is quite wrong for at least 2 reasons: `if (x == 1);` etc all have a semicolon `;` at the end of the  statement so it won't do what you want. And you should not call `main` from a function, it will recurse. Whether a function is defined in the code above or below `main` is irrelevant: what matters is the function prototype must have been compiled before any call is made to the function.

Comment: @WeatherVane ops, was the wrong link its been updated now and the code should be fine now

Comment: Please don't provide links to code: added to the question.

Comment: why do you pass the variables as arguments when you don't use anything passed from outside and just overwrite the values right away with scanf? Declare them as local variables instead

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free code design service nor a free coding service.  Please post a [mcve] of what you have tried and where the result is not what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check that `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2` and swap the coordinates around as necessary so that point (x1, y1) is bottom left and point (x2, y2) is top right.

Then check if the point is outside the box with

```
if(x < x1 || x > x2 || y < y1 || y > y2) {
    // outside the box
}
```

Then check if the point is inside the box with

```
else if(x > x1 && x < x2 && y > y1 && y < y2) {
    // inside the box
}
```

This leaves the case where

```
else {
    // on the box boundary
}
```

Strangely the function overwrites any arguments it is passed by using them as local variables. So the coordinates are lost when the function returns. It would be better to enter the data before calling the function, or pass pointers to variables that will contain the data.

---

**EDIT**

This is one way, although there are many ways the code could be improved. One difficulty of using the `double` type is the inexactness of the coding of floating point numbers. Note that the code avoids the use of the `==` equality test. That may not be an issue in this example, but if the point has been computed and should theoretically lie exactly on the box boundary, the testing might fail to detect that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { INSIDE, OUTSIDE, EDGE };

int throw_at_rectangle(double x, double y, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    if(x < x1 || x > x2 || y < y1 || y > y2) {
        // outside the box
        return OUTSIDE;
    }

    if(x > x1 && x < x2 && y > y1 && y < y2) {
        // inside the box
        return INSIDE;
    }

    // on the box boundary
    return EDGE;
}

int main(void) {

    double x1, y1;
    double x2, y2;
    double x, y;
    double temp;

    // First corner (bottom left) of the rectangle
    printf("Choose x and y for the first corner that the rectangle should start:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x1, &y1);

    // Opposite corner(top right) that should make the rectangle possible 
    printf("Choose x and y for the second corner that the rectangle should end:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x2, &y2);

    // The position of the point that should be checked
    printf("Choose the x and y that should be checked:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x, &y);

    if(x1 > x2) {
        temp = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = temp;
    }

    if(y1 > y2) {
        temp = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = temp;
    }

    switch(throw_at_rectangle(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2)) {
        case OUTSIDE:
            puts("outside the box");
            break;
        case INSIDE:
            puts("inside the box");
            break;
        default:
            puts("on the boundary");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you suggest I continue from your suggested code to the testing code since its something i need to use?